# How i can create/Update array based on user entered answer and linked question id from on change event of dynamic input in react.js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is my UI code where dynamic binding of input based on list

```
const listOfUserQuestions = shuffledUserQuesn.map((element, index) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Form layout="vertical" autoComplete="off">
                    <Form.Item label={element.question} >
                        <Input id={element.questionId} onChange={event => handleChange(index, event)} />
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
});
```

And below onchange function is to create array based on what user will enter in above input.

```
const [checkUserInput, setCheckUserInput] = useState([]);
function handleChange(i, e) {
    let exists = false;
    let updatedItemList = checkUserInput.map((item) => {
        if (item.questionId === e.target.id) {
            exists = true;
            return setCheckUserInput[{ ...item, userAnswer: e.target.value }];
        }
    });
    if (!exists) {
        setCheckUserInput((prevState) => [...checkUserInput, { ["questionId"]: e.target.id, ["userAnswer"]: e.target.value }]);
    } 
    console.log(checkUserInput)
}
```

and result should be in below json format see image
am able to create this type json [see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Mda.png) but when user enters more than one character answer in either first/second input i.e. questionId:8/questionId:3 then array values are not updating the array with new values and i can see only first inserted values

Comment: what output are you currently having in the console?

Comment: Am able to see only first inserted values in both the input. please refer attached screen shot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Mda.png

Comment: The rendering of the UI is done using: `shuffledUserQuesn.map`. And, when user makes changes, those are being updated to: `checkUserInput`. So, is there any logic which updates `shuffledUserQuesn` based on changes to `checkUserInput`?

Comment: shuffledUserQuesn is just an array with question and questionId . And there is nothing to do anything with this list. Its just used to bind but I'm facing issue during onchange of input unable to track user entered values in array

Answer (score 0):

Able to do it.

```
function handleChange(i, e) {
        let exists = false;
        checkUserInput.map((item) => {
            if (item.questionId === e.target.id) {
                exists = true;
                setCheckUserInput(prevValue =>
                    [...prevValue].map(el =>
                        el.questionId === e.target.id ? ({ ...el, userAnswer: e.target.value }) : el)
                )
            }
        });

        if (!exists) {
            setCheckUserInput((prevState) => [...checkUserInput, { ["questionId"]: e.target.id, ["userAnswer"]: e.target.value }]);
        }
    }
```